# aws - How to login cognito in Postman using POST request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to login cognito through Postman by POST request following the below site,
in order to get the id token from response.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

But it seems I am doing it by the wrong way, what is the correct way to do it?

[image]
[image]